# Tracking down data load performance issues in SSIS package

Tags: database, performance, ssis

Are there any ways to determine what the differences in databases are that affect a SSIS package load performance ?

I've got a package which loads and does various bits of processing on ~100k records on my laptop database in about 5 minutes

Try the same package and same data on the test server, which is a reasonable box in both CPU and memory, and it's still running ... about 1 hour so far :-(
Checked the package with a small set of data, and it ran through Ok

Comment: When you point the package at your servers...are you still running the package from your laptop in BI Studio?

Comment: My local set-up is two VMWare Workstation virtuals, one with SQL Server, the other is my Visual Studio machine with the SSIS package. The test environment is again two virtuals, again one with SQL, one with the package on, but hosted on our ESX cluster.

Comment: It just gets more baffling ...
- put the package on the SQL server box, tried running it with a few records, loads fine, ramp up to a few hundred, still ok, then a two thousand ... stops dead on a data flow task.
The task is pushing data from a view into a couple of tables, one pretty much straight, the other with a lookup and a few extra columns 
But on my laptop a test file with much bigger data files ran in 5 minutes !!

Comment: I've found the limit is 1044 records and it works in 5 seconds, but go to 1045 records and it blocks at the data flow ... just what limit is there that cause this sort of thing, when thousands of records work fine on my laptop ?

Comment: And if I run it in Visual Studio, it manages 9947 records and then just sits there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CozyRoc over at [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/c168ee07-dbf1-4433-b122-b5037788047b) pointed me in the right direction ...

- used the SSMS / Management / Activity Monitor and spotted lots of TRANSACTION entries

- got me thinking, read up on the Ole Db connector and unchecked the Table Lock 

- WHAM ... data loads fine  :-)

Still don't understand why it works fine on my laptop d/b, and stalls on the test server ?

- I was the only person using the test d/b, so it's not as if there should have been any contention for the tables ??

Comment: Steve - I've been battling performance problems on SSIS for a month now. While inconclusive, it seems as though SSIS doesn't perform as well on x64 servers as it does on 32-bit machines. A case study of a 200GB Oracle -> SQL load, a blog on MSDN, and my own findings all point towards the same thing... OLE DB on x64 has got some performance flaws. Run SSIS *on* the database server, and watch how network I/O screams up even when using named pipes connections.

Answer (score 4):

I've had similar problems over the past few weeks, and here are several things you could consider, listed in decreasing order of importance according to what made the biggest difference for us:

1. **Don't *assume* anything about the server.**
   We found that our production server's RAID was miscconfigured (HP sold us disks with firmware mismatches) and the disk write speed was literally a 50th of what it should be. So check out the server metrics with Perfmon.
2. **Check that enough RAM is allocated to SQL Server**. Inserts of large datasets often require use of RAM and TempDB for building indices, etc. Ensure that SQL has enough RAM that it doesn't need to swap out to Pagefile.sys.
3. As per the holy grail of SSIS, **avoid manipulating large datasets using T-SQL** statements. All T-SQL statements cause changed data to write out to the transaction log *even if you use Simple Recovery Model*. The only difference between Simple and Full recovery models is that Simple automatically truncates the log file *after* each transactions. This means that large datasets, when manipulated with T-SQL, thrash the log file, killing performance.
4. For large datasets, **do data sorts at the source** if possible. The SSIS Sort component chokes on reasonably large datasets, and the only viable alternative (nSort by Ordinal, Inc.) costs $900 for a non-transferrable per CPU license. So... if you absolutely have to a large dataset then consider loading it into a staging database as an intermediate step.
5. **Use the SQL Server Destination** if you know your package is going to run on the destination server, since it offers roughly 15% performance increase over OLE DB because it shares memory with SQL Server.
6. **Increase the network packaet size to 32767 on your database connection managers**. This allows large volumes of data to move faster from the source server/s, and can noticably improve reads on large datasets.
7. If using Lookup transforms, **experiment with cache sizes** - between using a Cache connection or Full Cache mode for smaller lookup datasets, and Partial / No Cache for larger datasets. This can free up much needed RAM.
8. If combining multiple large datasets, use either RAW files or a staging database to hold your transformed datasets, then combine and **insert all of a table's data in a single data flow operation**, and lock the destination table. Using staging tables or RAW files can also help relive table locking contention.
9. Last but not least, **experiment with the DefaultBufferSize and DefaulBufferMaxRows** properties. You'll need to monitor your package's "Buffers Spooled" performance counter using Perfmon.exe, and adjust the buffer sizes *upwards* until you see buffers being spooled (paged to disk), then back off a little.

Point 8 is especially important on very large datasets, since you can only achieve a minimally logged bulk insert operation if:

- The destination table is empty, and
- The table is locked for the duration of the load operation.
- The database is in Simply / Bulk Logged recovery mode.

This means that subesquent bulk loads a table will always be fully logged, so you want to get as much data as possible into the table on the first data load.

Finally, if you can partition you destination table and then load the data into each partition in parallel, you can achieve up to 2.5 times faster load times, though this isn't usually a feasible option out in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

If you've ruled out network latency, your most likely culprit (with real quantities of data) is your pipeline organisation. Specifically, what transformations you're doing along the pipeline.

Data transformations come in four flavours:

- streaming (entirely in-process/in-memory)
- non-blocking (but still using I/O, e.g. lookup, oledb commands)
- semi-blocking (blocks a pipeline partially, but not entirely, e.g. merge join)
- blocking (blocks a pipeline until it's entirely received, e.g. sort, aggregate)

If you've a few blocking transforms, that will significantly mash your performance on large datasets. Even semi-blocking, on unbalanced inputs, will block for long periods of time.

Comment: Could you explain how to rule out network latency, as it's completely new to me?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the biggest performance factor in SSIS is **Network Latency**.  A package running locally on the server itself runs much faster than anything else on the network.  Beyond that I can't think of any reasons why the speed would be drastically different.  Running SQL Profiler for a few minutes may yield some clues there.

Comment: Interesting you reckon network latency is the biggest performance hit ... the test environment is two servers, one with package, one with SQL, so it's going over the network ... could that have such a big hit ?